# How can i refresh the datagrid to show the new values?

Tags: datagrid, dojo

I developed a web GIS tool to find some features on map using Find task of ArcGIS javascript api and show the attribute in a grid using grid enhanced of dojo. everything work fine at the first time. I can find features using keywords and show attributes in the grid but when i use the find tool again , I only can show the features on map and the grid not refresh after the first use. How can i Refresh and show new values in the grid?
the [geonet](https://geonet.esri.com/thread/44459) has a code sample like my code . I search in the stackoverflow and found the [how-to-refresh-datagrid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5499453/how-to-refresh-datagrid) but i could not use the solutions.

```js
define([
    "esri/tasks/FindTask",
    "esri/tasks/FindParameters",
    "esri/symbols/SimpleLineSymbol",
    "esri/symbols/SimpleFillSymbol",
    "esri/Color",

    "dgrid/Grid",
    "dgrid/Selection",
    'dojo/_base/declare',
    "dojo/on",
    "dojo/dom",
    "dijit/registry",
    "dojo/_base/array",
    "dijit/form/Button",
    "dojo/parser",
    "esri/symbols/SimpleMarkerSymbol","dojo/data/ItemFileReadStore","dojox/grid/EnhancedGrid","dojo/data/ItemFileWriteStore",
    "dojox/grid/enhanced/plugins/Pagination","dojox/grid/enhanced/plugins/Selector","dojox/grid/enhanced/plugins/Filter","dojox/grid/enhanced/plugins/exporter/CSVWriter","dojo/io/iframe",
    "dojo/domReady!"],function ( FindTask, FindParameters, SimpleLineSymbol, SimpleFillSymbol, Color,
                                Grid, Selection, declare, on, dom, registry, arrayUtils, Button, parser,SimpleMarkerSymbol,ItemFileReadStore,EnhancedGrid,ItemFileWriteStore) {
        return{

            Find: function (map) {

                var findTask, findParams;

                var grid, store;




                parser.parse();

                registry.byId("searchfind").on("click", doFind);

                //Create Find Task using the URL of the map service to search
                findTask = new FindTask("http://...:6080/arcgis/rest/services/layers2/MapServer/");

                map.on("load", function () {
                    //Create the find parameters
                    findParams = new FindParameters();
                    findParams.returnGeometry = true;
                    findParams.layerIds = [0];
                    findParams.searchFields = ["Name"];
                    findParams.outSpatialReference = map.spatialReference;
                    console.log("find sr: ", findParams.outSpatialReference);
                });

                function doFind() {
                    //Set the search text to the value in the box
                    var ownerNameBox = dom.byId("findName");
                    findParams.searchText = dom.byId("findName").value;
                    findTask.execute(findParams, showResults);
                }
                function showFilterBar(){
                    dijit.byId('grid').showFilterBar(true);
                }

                function showResults(results) {

                    //This function works with an array of FindResult that the task returns
                    map.graphics.clear();
                    var symbol = new SimpleMarkerSymbol();
                    symbol.setColor(new Color([0,255,255]));

                    //create array of attributes
                    var items = dojo.map(results, function (result) {
                        var graphic = result.feature;
                        graphic.setSymbol(symbol);
                        map.graphics.add(graphic);
                        return result.feature.attributes;
                    });
                    var data = {
                        identifier: 'OBJECTID',
                        label:'OBJECID',
                        items: items
                    };



                   
                     store = new dojo.data.ItemFileReadStore({data: data});

                    /*set up layout*/
                    var layout = [[
                        {'name': 'OBJECTID', 'field': 'OBJECTID', 'width':'9em',datatype:"number"},
                        {'name': 'Name', 'field': 'Name','width':'16em',datatype:"string",autocomplete:true},
                        {'name':'Address','field':'Address','width':'18em',datatype:"string",autocomplete:true}

                    ]];

                    /*create a new grid:*/
                    var grid = new dojox.grid.EnhancedGrid({

                            id: 'grid',
                            store:store,
                            structure: layout, rowSelector: '1px',
                            plugins: {
                                // pagination: {
                                //     pageSizes: ["5", "10", "All"],
                                //     description: true,
                                //     sizeSwitch: false,
                                //     pageStepper: true,
                                //     gotoButton: true,
                                //     /*page step to be displayed*/
                                //     maxPageStep: 3,
                                //     /*position of the pagination bar*/
                                //     position: "bottom"
                                // },
                                filter: {
                                    // Show the closeFilterbarButton at the filter bar
                                    closeFilterbarButton: true
                                    // Set the maximum rule count to 5
                                    // ruleCount: 5,
                                    // Set the name of the items
                                    // itemsName: "songs",

                                }

                            }

                            },

                        document.createElement('div'));

                    /*append the new grid to the div*/

                    dojo.byId("grid").appendChild(grid.domNode);



                    /*Call startup() to render the grid*/

                    grid.startup();
                    grid.setStore(store);
                    grid.refresh()





                }
                //Zoom to the parcel when the user clicks a row




                    //display the results in the grid



                    //Zoom back to the initial map extent
                    // map.centerAndZoom(center, zoom);


                // //Zoom to the parcel when the user clicks a row
                function onRowClickHandler(evt) {
                    var clickedTaxLotId = event.rows[0].data.BRTID;
                    var selectedTaxLot = arrayUtils.filter(map.graphics.graphics, function (graphic) {
                        return ((graphic.attributes) && graphic.attributes.BRTID === clickedTaxLotId);
                    });
                    if ( selectedTaxLot.length ) {
                        map.setExtent(selectedTaxLot[0].geometry.getExtent(), true);
                    }
                }

            }


        }



    }


)
```

```html
<body  class="claro" role="main">
<div id="appLayout"  style="width:100%; height:100%;" >
        </div>
    <!--<div id="rightpane">-->
    <!--</div>-->
    <div id="center">
      <!-->
some divs
<!-->
</div>
          <div id="bottom" style="height: 330px" >

    </button>

        <div id="grid" style="height:98%;font-size: 14px" ></div>
</div>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to change change values in the grid, you will need to change the value in the grid's store. The dojo grid widget will update itself as needed as it is directly liked to your store.

Comment: Here an example found on the web showing how to refresh data in a dojo grid widget: http://jsfiddle.net/v6xbtwfz/

Comment: I debug my code using chrome debugger. the stores values are correct . at the first time the code create the grid using "var grid = new dojox.grid.EnhancedGrid" .at other times the stores get the new values but it can not recreate grid using "var grid = new dojox.grid.EnhancedGrid" . I think i should create the grid once but i don't know how to create the grid once and use it repeatedly

Comment: @wetland please create a jsfiddle with a minim code and dependencies to reproduce your problem I can try to fix it for you and give you a solution. Please post here thanks!